# Create a string from an array

Tags: php

I have an array:

```
array(
 array('w' => '100', 'h'=>'100'),
 array('w' => '200', 'h'=>'200'),
 array('w' => '300', 'h'=>'300')
)
```

I ned to create a string from this array that looks like:

```
[100, 100], [200, 200], [300, 300]
```

I've looked at:

```
array_values()
```

I use it by looping through each array to remove the key, but what would be the best way to make the entire string, with square brackets?

Comment: @panthro If you add a surrounding `[...]`, it's perfectly fine JSON.

Comment: @deceze That's true, its only the removed surrounding `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to format along with some basic string concat like this:

```
$string='';
foreach($mainArray as $v)
{
    $string.='['.(implode(',',$v)).'],';
}
$string=substr($string,0,-1);
```

The last bit wioll remove the trailing comma from the foreach statement.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `json_encode()`:

```
$values = array(
     array('w' => '100', 'h'=>'100'),
     array('w' => '200', 'h'=>'200'),
     array('w' => '300', 'h'=>'300'),
);

$new_values = array();
foreach ($values as $value) {
    // put cast int @Tash:
    $new_values[] = json_encode(array((int)$value['w'], (int)$value['h']));
}

echo implode(',', $new_values); // [100,100],[200,200],[300,300]
```

Comment: This is not correct, your commented output is different from actual output, the actual output has quotes ["100","100"],["200","200"] how can I remove these?

Comment: @deceze thank you array values is much suitable, and for online code

Comment: Cast the the values to int like so: ... array('w' => (int) 100, 'h' => (int) 100), ... //etc

Comment: This answer is not correct as quotes appear around each string. Json encode is not the correct way to do this.

Comment: @user3729576 its okay now since tash pointed out to cast it to int, so it removes quotes

Comment: but I have other examples that are strings, so it wouldn't work would it

Answer (score 0):

```
$tmp = array(
    array('w' => 100, 'h' => 100),
    array('w' => 200, 'h' => 200),
    array('w' => 300, 'h' => 300)
);
$str = '';
foreach ($tmp as $i => $value) {
    if ($i == 0)
        $str = '[' . implode(',', $value) . ']';
    else
        $str.= ', [' . implode(',', $value) . ']';
}
var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array(
 array('w' => 100, 'h'=>100),
 array('w' => 200, 'h'=>200),
 array('w' => 300, 'h'=>300)
);
$str='';
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
    $str .= '['.$val['w'].','.$val['h'].'],';
}
$str = substr($str,0,-1);
echo $str;
```

Comment: do please explain how this piece of code does the work, so it will be helpful to community. see [answer]

Comment: all you need to add to put your array in it, and rest you can see, i can polish it a bit so that you can understand better

Answer (score 0):

That is Json.

Try this, even though not so clean.

```
<?php
$ace=array(
 array('w' => 100, 'h'=>100),
 array('w' => 200, 'h'=>200),
 array('w' => 300, 'h'=>300)
);
$json="";
foreach($ace as $key=>$value){
    $json.= json_encode(array($value['w'],$value['h'])) . ",";
}
echo substr($json,0,-1);//remove last comma
```

Comment: It's not JSON! JSON would have quotes around each string

Comment: Try this and you will see its a json. `<?php
$ace=array(
 array('w' => 100, 'h'=>100),
 array('w' => 200, 'h'=>200),
 array('w' => 300, 'h'=>300)
);
foreach($ace as $key=>$value){
 $arr[]=array($value['w'],$value['h']);
}
echo json_encode($arr);`
The values of `'w'` and `'h'` are integers so they are not quoted.